# wifi doesn't work on lenovo G500 with ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, lenovo, atheros

I have been using ubuntu for more than 10 years but this is first time I could not get around an issue with a solution. Any help would be great as I have tried everything available that I found on the internet.

I have a QCA8172 atheros ethernet adapter on a lenovo G500. It works when a cable is attached but there is no wifi at all.

I tried to post a image, but it didn't let me add a pic.

I tried with backports and with also compact drivers but still have the same issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Lenovo-G500:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280 – 
grep: –: No such file or directory

Comment: The trailing - is not part of the command. The forum adds that between the comment and the poster's name. Pleas try again: lspci -nn | grep 0280 with no trailing dash.

Comment: lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Answer (score 2):

Your 14e4:4365 device works with the Broadcom STA driver in Ubuntu 13.10. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Do you now have a wireless interface, ideally eth1?

```
iwconfig
```

Does it scan and see networks?

```
sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

If there are errors, post them here.

If you previously attempted the compat-wireless package, you will need to uninstall it so as to resolve a probable conflict:

```
cd ~/Desktop/compat-wireless-whichever
```

Or compat-drivers or whichever you attempted to install.

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Reboot. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up fakeroot (1.20-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-17-generic
G500:~$ sudo modprobe wl
ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument
Lenovo-G500:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.


eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I started reading this tethering off my phone and now I'm using our wifi. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 12.04 LTS, and here's what I did: I rebooted my Laptop, and clicked on ''Try Ubuntu'', than I installed Wi-Fi driver on that ''trial'' Ubntu, and after that I installed it via shortcut on the desktop, and everything worked nice.

If you want, you could try this, I hope it will work :)